# jquery selector wont find body

Tags: jquery, html

[image: Chrome dev]

I cant select the body tag in the above, everything is coming back as an empty object.  I can select the body in google ok, whats causing this. the page was fine in w3s validation

Comment: Not sure what you mean, your query for body is returning a jQuery object with one element as it should

Comment: @juan mendes-I was expecting actual html

Comment: Still doesn't make sense... I guarantee you it behaves exactly as it did on Google. How did you get the HTML there? Here's a clue https://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was assuming that I would get an HTML response back when the selector had 1 or more results like:
[image]

Instead of a function styled response such as above, but I can see that one response was found now and have fixed the issue that was causing the error